# ¿se puede poner una imagen en un degradado como background en android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas, así como dice la pregunta, quisiera saber si en un fondo degradado se puede poner una imagen pequeña ya sea en el centro o en cualquier lugar del diseño, y todo esto ponerlo como background de una actividad.

Que yo sepa los degradados se crean en el directorio "Drawable" y con la etiquita:

```
 < shape> < /shape>
```

pero, adicionalmente a esto, quería saber si a este fondo se le puede añadir una imagen que forme parte del fondo todo en conjunto ya que no sé si hay una etiqueta que permita eso o tengo que crear otro archivo y juntar ambos recursos(uno del degradado y otro de la imagen).

Espero alguna ayuda jeje Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede, usa lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="5dp">
            <corners
                 android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
         </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/nombre_de_tu_imagen />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, intenté con la forma que comentaste pero me daba el error que al asignarle colores al gradiant, este tapaba a la imagen pero luego les cambie de lugar en el orden del etiquetas, primero la etiqueta shape y luego la imagen y sí me dio!! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Okey!, me lo apunto y lo actualizo, me alegra de que te haya servido

Answer (score 0):

Crea un gradiente dentro del folder `\drawable` por ejemplo gradiente.xml, donde principalmente defines el color inicial y final, en este ejemplo se define un color verde como inicial:

```
   android:startColor="00FF00"
```

y un color negro como final:

```
   android:endColor="#000000"
```

archivo `gradiente.xml` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="00FF00"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Este gradiente se asigna como `background` en el layout y como `foreground` la imagen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/androide"
    android:background="@drawable/gradiente">
</LinearLayout>
```

para obtener como resultado la imagen y como fondo el gradiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es bueno comentar la razón de -1, esto para mejorar la respuesta o saber si se tiene algún problema.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!! A simple vista sí es lo que pedí pero lo que pasa es que cuando pongo la imagen como "foreground" tapa el contenido que debería ir adelante del background. he ahí mi problema con el método que planteas :(