# Diseño en aplicaciones móviles

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Buen día, ¿alguien sabe como puedo hacer un marco como este para mi aplicación móvil desarrollada en Android Studio, donde también se pueda mostrar información?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El texto de "Información General" parece tener un background con una gradiante y un borde, en el siguiente hilo a un usuario le explican como colocar un background (fondo) con degradado [ver aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130018/se-puede-poner-una-imagen-en-un-degradado-como-background-en-android). En el segundo cuadro puedes crear un layout que contenga los textView y agregarle un background el cual contenga ese borde de color verde y el borde redondo. Te recomiendo ver la siguiente pagina donde explican muy detalladamente como crear estos archivos en drawables y aplicarlos a tu

Comment: Buenos días, te recomiendo que leas [ask], y rehagas tu pregunta. Deberías poner lo que has intentado y no esperar a que te den la solución a tu problema

Comment: La forma más común es tener una imagen con ese marco, preferentemente usar un drawable nine patch para que se muestre correctamente en todos los tamaños de pantalla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder